# What is the meaning of wget -O -

Tags: wget

I am trying to install dropbox onto my Debian machine, and I saw the instruction

```
cd ~ && wget -O - "some website leading to the download of a tar file" | tar xzf -
```

But what I did was just typing this:

```
wget -O - "some website leading to the download of a tar file"
```

and I got a lot of rubbish on my terminal. What does  `wget -O -` means? Does it do any harm to my computer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at the man page for `wget`.

```
-O file
   --output-document=file
       The documents will not be written to the appropriate files, but all
       will be concatenated together and written to file.  If - is used as
       file, documents will be printed to standard output, disabling link
       conversion.  (Use ./- to print to a file literally named -.)

       Use of -O is not intended to mean simply "use the name file instead
       of the one in the URL;" rather, it is analogous to shell redirection:
       wget -O file http://foo is intended to work like 
       wget -O - http://foo > file; file will be truncated immediately, and
       all downloaded content will be written there.
```

So you can either download the contents of "URL" to a file using `-O somefile` or you can download it and redirect its contents via STDOUT to another tool to do something with it. In this case that's what they're doing with the `| tar xvf -`.

Your command:

```
$ cd ~ && wget -O - "some website leading to the download of a tar file" | tar xzf -
```

The above is taking the tarball from the "URL" and as it's being downloaded it's being redirected to the command `tar` so that it can be unpacked into your filesystem.

Comment: I often see in places where one has to download APT repository key the usage `wget -O- https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt/keys.asc | gpg --dearmor > signal-desktop-keyring.gpg`. Mind there is no space after the big letter O and the dash is right after it. First it looked strange to me, but it is common behaviour of the Linux parameters. One can put values without delimiting them from the letter of parameter. I did it often when connecting with ssh on non default port (`ssh -p6666`) or passing user and password to MySQL CLI client (`mysql -psecretpassword -uadmin`)

Comment: @slm How the `tar` commands extract the `STDOUT`? I mean the output looks like a bunch of strings.

Answer (score 1):

`wget -O - <url>` means that wget will download the url and print the file to STDOUT, hence the garbage in your terminal.  The full command pipes that output to `tar xzf` to extract and (presumably) produce useful files.

Answer (score 0):

```
wget -O | gzip -c > file_name.gz
```

it mean  wget get the data from www regardless their type. and output that file. it is either html or file from ftp.

and gzip will write that file in the compressed form.

for more info read the help

```
$ man wget  
$ man gzip 
$ wget --help  ( for just option of the wget)
$ gzip --help
```

Comment: there is not  hyphen after. before O it is required for short option.  Some people use this just - and url. That is - point to url I think.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the use case to understand `wget -O`.

to download a single file

```
wget http://machineintellect.cn/testfile.zip
```

this command will download a file, and name it `testfile.zip`, which is after the last `/`

but, if u use `wget` directly on an URL like this

```
wget http://machineintellect.cn/download?id=1
```

the downloaded file will be named like `download.aspx?id=1080`, which is not what u want.

so, u can use `-O` to specify the target local file name, like this

```
wget -O target-local.zip http://machineintellect.cn/download.aspx?id=1080
```

this command will give u a file named target-local.zip

Comment: It doesn't answer the question: *What is the meaning of wget -O -*