# Understanding the command “wget -q -O- | apt-key add -”

Tags: command-line, wget

I am trying to understand this command:

```
#wget -q https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg -O- | apt-key add -
```

- `wget -q`
  Download the open keyrings but should not output anything
- `-O-`
  Here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/83835/374478 explain that redirect its contents to apt-key
- `apt-key add -`
  Add the open keyrings from **php** to to the apt sources keyring.

so, later I can Download **PHP** .

Have I understood it correctly?

Comment: Thanks, I will now learn it, you know another Platz where explain it with easy Words?

Comment: I put the URL back: https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository/UseThirdParty (for the "newer" recommended method)

Comment: How understand, for security the open keyrings MUSS to save on /usr/share/keyrings and later on Sources.list, build a File on /etc/apt/sources.list.d/deriv.list and add my keyring.gpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's pretty much it. The `-O-` actually sends the output to standard output. Then the pipe symbol connects (makes a pipe between) that standard ouput and the standard input of apt-key. Lastly, you tell apt-key to read the information from it's standard input (the "-" filename
 at the end).

Comment: very thanks to you, I asked it because I am to trying to write guidance on how to install PHP on Linux.. thank for (the - flag at the end), I don't knew it...